# Pyspark | Split multiple array column into rows

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following PySpark DF:

| key | percentile_approx(0.25,0.5,0.75) |
| --- | --- |
| avg_wh | [1.5, 6.5, 4.5] |

And I want to turn it into:

| key | value | metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| avg_wh | 1.5 | 0.25 |
| avg_wh | 6.5 | 0.5 |
| avg_wh | 4.5 | 0.75 |

Can someone help with exploding and renaming and adding the column? thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) method (but I don't know where metrics come from with your snippet)